# How to get rid of title in multibib

Tags: bibliographies, subdividing, multibib

This is my first question here. I'm not a LaTeX expert and I'm writing my theses now. 
Anyway, I had to use `multibib` so that I can list my publications towards the beginning of the theses document and also still have the full bibliography at the end.

However, I ran into many problems that were fixed. 
The only problem I'm having now is that I want to get rid of the title associated with the references I'm using to list my publications. 
This is what I'm using now:

```
\usepackage{multibib}
\newcites{nu}{I don't want this title}
```

I want to get rid of the title because the template I'm using already specifies a title for that section. How do I go about this?

I tried

```
\newcites{nu}{}
```

but that did not work and is giving me 'undefined control sequence errors' whenever i refer to nu such as in `\nocitenu{w1,w2}...etc`

I also tried to change the font color of the title to match the background and thus disappear, but that also did not work.

Any thoughts?